# Better method than float:right in navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I have made a horizontal navigation bar using styles, but I've encountered a major issue... Since `<li>` is a block element, I can't align it using `text-align:right`, which makes me unable to align it properly. I've tried using the `display:inline;` syntax for the list-item element, but that doesn't make any difference either (which makes sense actually).

My question being, is there any way of aligning horizontal `<li>`, without having to use `float:right;`? I want it to fit the current list's format (which I've adjusted to fit a parent div), and using float isn't really a good or safe method. [Here's](http://prntscr.com/1z1vi1) a screenshot of what I got so far (layout is slightly messed up due to recent addition of image). As you can see, I have managed to get the "My page" and "Log out" properly placed, but as soon as I add something more "complex" (like the "+", which now is placed in the normal list), it gets screwed up... I really don't get how other websites manages to get this right.

Comment: post your code please using jsfiddle

Comment: did you explicitly declare them as `block`? because `li`s are `display:list-item;` by default. => http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-display

Comment: @PlantTheIdeal I did declare `list-style-type:none;` and `display:inline;` for the chosen list items. But, I didn't really know that they were "list-items" as default and not "blocks". Though, that doesn't change anything does it?

Comment: Also, I'll go a head and edit the question, to add the things I declared in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You must define [`text-align: right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) for the *containing* element

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="menu">1</li>
    <li class="menu">2</li>
    <li class="menu">3</li>
    <li class="menu">4</li>
    <li class="menu">5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    text-align: right;
}

.menu {
    display: inline;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nucyX/)

You can split the menu to a left and right part, if you like. Add or remove padding and margin as needed

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav left-nav">
    <li class="menu">1</li>
    <li class="menu">2</li>
    <li class="menu">3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav right-nav">
    <li class="menu">4</li>
    <li class="menu">5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.left-nav {
    text-align: left;
}

.right-nav {
    text-align: right;
}

.menu {
    display: inline;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nucyX/1/)

Comment: Great information, really! However, I sort of need half the menu to be on one side, and creating a new ul-element seems to create space... Here's a picture of what I mean: http://prntscr.com/1z21fk (and I tried using `span` and stuff too, but that wasn't effective)

Comment: You can have two lists, one for the left and one for the right part. See updated answer.

Comment: The problem though is, that I'm experiencing space between the two. Here's a new list I made (using only your code, and my special div): http://prntscr.com/1z268a . As you can see, the div is a bit stretched. I sort of want them to appear on the same "line".

Comment: Then you must return to `float: left` and `float: right`, see this  http://jsfiddle.net/nucyX/2/, or use `position: absolute`, see here http://jsfiddle.net/nucyX/3/

Comment: Thanks tons for explaining that to me. I decided to just go a head and use `float:right;` and `float:left`, since you're stating that it's a must. Now it works, since I combined these with `overflow-y:auto;`, which still made the div's height adjustable, hence the background clearly visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go i think this is what you are looking for:

jsfiddle.net/Sdw5h/

Comment: This is the method I've been using, but unfortunately it concludes `float:right`, which is what I don't really want in this context. EDIT: Hold on, just saw something interesting... I'll look further into your answer.

Comment: This method would work too, but it's a bit too different from the (somewhat complex) original code (and, I'm not too comfortable using the `<nav>` tag... Feels kind of new to me, which might mean compatibility issues with older browsers). Thanks anyways though.

Comment: you can change the <nav> to a <div id="nav"> and on the css call it like this #nav